# Add item to LinkedList located in another class

Tags: java, class, linked-list

My linked list in Client class:

```
private LinkedList<Client> clients = new LinkedList<Client>();
```

These are methods located in Client class:

```
public LinkedList<Client> getCList() {
        return clients;
    }

public void addClientList( Client newclient) {
        clients.add(newclient);
    }
```

In another class called UInterface I am trying to add some elements to my list:

```
Client klientasTemp2 = new Client (nameT, surnameT, numberT, moneyT, addressT);
    klientasTemp.addClientList(klientasTemp);
for (int i=0; i<klientasTemp.getClientLenght(); i++)    
    System.out.println(klientasTemp.getCList());
```

For some reason all I get is:

```
[    0.0,     0.0]
```

I know it should be easy but I really can not understand where I made mistake. Thanks guys!

Comment: You are initializing "klientasTemp2" but adding "klientasTemp".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

`klientasTemp.addClientList(klientasTemp);` to

```
klientasTemp.addClientList(klientasTemp2);
```

And also when you print `LinkedList<Client>()`, it will invoke the `toString()` method on each of `Client` Object. So make sure the '`toString()`' returns what you want to see in output.

Answer (score 1):

You state:

```
   Client **klientasTemp2** = new Client (nameT, surnameT, numberT, moneyT, addressT);
        ***klientasTemp***.addClientList(***klientasTemp***);
```

You make `klientasTemp2`, but are adding to `klientasTemp`.

So, `klientasTemp2` will stay empty.